# How to download and save arrays of files to my local PC in php

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, force-download

I am currently using a simple html dom to scrape a website, part of the contents I scrape are : images, links, and text.  Now what I need to accomplish is to save the scraped data to my local PC or database. Is there a way I can accomplish this using php?

To force download those contents at once to my PC or database.

Will upload my codes if you feel it's necessary.
Thank you in advance...

Edited: Here is my code...

```
   include("../dom/simple_html_dom.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))

       {
    if ($_POST['word1'] != ""){

        //posts of the search query

        $word1 = $_POST['word1'];


       $items = array('url'=>'https://www.example.com/mobile-phones/?q='.str_replace(' ','+',$word1)."/",'img'=>'.image-wrapper img','brand'=>'h2.title span.brand','name'=>'h2.title span.name','price'=>'span.price-box','link'=>'section.products a.link');

$site = new simple_html_dom();

$currentImg = '';
$currentItemBrand = '';
$currentItemName = '';
$currentLink = '';
$currentPrice = '';

$counter = 0;
$number = -1;


    $site->load_file($items['url']);

    $currentImg = array();
    $currentItemBrand = $site->find($items["brand"]);
    $currentItemName = $site->find($items["name"]);
    $currentLink = $site->find($items["link"]);
    $currentPrice = $site->find($items["price"]);

    foreach($site->find($items["img"]) as $element) {
        $counter2++;    
    //initializing array objects

    if($counter2 % 2 == 0 && $counter2 < 42)
        {

        $number++;
        $currentImg = $element[$number]->src;
        $currentItemName[$number]->plaintext;
        $currentItemBrand2[$number]->plaintext;
        $currentLink[$number]->href;
        $currentPrice[$number]->plaintext;

                }
            }


    // My Database Code

    $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO items (img, name, link, price, brand) VALUES ('$currentImg', '$currentItemName', '$currentItemLink','$currentPrice','$currentItemBrand')";

    mysqli_select_db($elecom_connect,$database_elecom_connect);
    $Result1 = mysqli_query($elecom_connect,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error($elecom_connect));
    exit();

                    }                               

                }
            }

    ?>
```

The issue I have with this code is that it only save a reference of the images, to the database...What I want is to download all the arrays of files and then store them in my database....I am a bit confused on how to do that....Will appreciate your suggestions or codes block.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Yes, show all relevant code (kept to a minimum).  Present some sample input, your expected output, your database structure, what you've tried so far, and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: OK, will do that now, let me get hold of my laptop.. Thank you for your urgent response

Comment: I have updated my question